# TYPO3 multicolumn image shrink

Tags: typo3, typoscript, multiple-columns

I have got a problem with the multicolumn imageshrink function.

There is a three column layout where the imageshrink function (first column) works perfectly. But in my two column layout, the shrink function seems to work, but the imagewidth is always 450px, but if must be 280px. Any ideas?

TSConfig root page:

```
tx_multicolumn.layoutPreset >
tx_multicolumn.layoutPreset {

# Define a unique key for the layout
twoColumnLayout {

# Backend label (path to a locallang file)
label = 2 Spalten

# Icon (file resource or a path to fileadmin)
icon = fileadmin/layout/images/multi2spalten.png

config {

  #Width of multicolumn container (px or %)
  containerMeasure = px

  containerWidth = 900

  # Number of columns(integer)
  columns = 2

  # Column measure (px or %)
  columnMeasure = px

  # Column width (integer, optionSplit)
  columnWidth = 580 |*| 280

  # Column margin (string, optionSplit)
  columnMargin = 0 20px 0 0 |*| 0 0 0 0

  # Disable auto image shrink for columns (boolean, 0)
  disableImageShrink = 0

  }
}


# Define a unique key for the layout
threeColumnLayout {

# Backend label (path to a locallang file)
label = 3 Spalten

# Icon (file resource or a path to fileadmin)
icon = fileadmin/layout/images/multi3spalten.png

config {

  #Width of multicolumn container (px or %)
  containerMeasure = px

  containerWidth = 900

  # Number of columns(integer)
  columns = 3

  # Column measure (px or %)
  columnMeasure = px

  # Column width (integer, optionSplit)
  columnWidth = 300 |*| 260 |*| 260

  # Column margin (string, optionSplit)
  columnMargin = 0 20px 0 0 |*| 0 20px 0 0 |*| 0 0 0 0

  # Disable auto image shrink for columns (boolean, 0)
  disableImageShrink = 0

  }
}
}
```

Main Template Constants:

```
styles.content.imgtext.colPos0.maxW = 280
styles.content.imgtext.colPos1.maxW = 280
styles.content.imgtext.colPos2.maxW = 280
styles.content.imgtext.colPos3.maxW = 280
```

Main Template Setup:

```
tt_content.image.20.maxW.cObject = CASE
tt_content.image.20.maxW.cObject {
key.field = colPos
## Normal
0 = TEXT
0.value = 280
## Left
1 = TEXT
1.value = 280
## Right
2 = TEXT
2.value = 280
## Border
3 = TEXT
3.value = 280
}
```

Comment: Did you check in typoscript object browser?

Comment: yes, but I don't know where are the 450px definded. :/

Comment: Okay I found it out: he takes the 900px width of the containerwidth and devides it with the numberof columns, but why does he doesn't take the columnwidth that I defined?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself, but thanks anyway.

Here is the solution:

**I set the containerMeasure to % instead of px and the containerWidth to 100.**

That was all, now the shrink works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below typoscript setup:

```
tt_content.image.20.maxW = 280px
```